# Symmetric group action on polynomial ring

Tags: polynomials, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, symmetric-polynomials, invariant-theory

Let the symmetric group $S_4$ act on $\mathbb R[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4]$ by permuting the 1st $4$ variables and again permuting the last $4$ variables. We can restrict the action to the alternating group $A_4$. It seems there is a degree $4$ polynomial which is invariant under the $A_4$ action but not invariant under the $S_4$ action. But I can't figure out what is that polynomial. Any help in this direction will be helpful.

Comment: Are you familiar with the proof that the parity of a permutation (defined as the parity of the number of transpositions in *any* expression of the permutation as a product of transpositions) is well defined, by acting on a discriminant?

Comment: yes, I am familiar with even and odd permutations. But here the discriminant is of degree $36$.

Comment: You only need to do it with some of the variables, since the action is independent. You only need to figure out how to drop it from 6 to 4, not from 36 to 4.

Comment: Yes, I tried all possible degree 4 combinations like (x_i-y_j).... but it doesn't work.

Comment: I just forgot to mention that the action is same on both $x_i$'s and $y_j$'s. This action is coming from the diagonal action on $\mathbb R^4 \oplus \mathbb R^4$.

Comment: No, the point is that it acts on the $x$s separately from how it acts on the $y$s. You should look at polynomials that contain only $x$s, only $y$s, or have them in separate monomials that mirror each other. For example, if you just take the discriminant of the $x$s, $\prod_{i\lt j}(x_j-x_i)$, then this is invariant under the action of $A_4$ but not under the action of $S_4$. (And you could of course take the sum of the discriminant of the $x$s and the discriminant of the $y$s). I know this is degree 6, not 4, but you shouldn't be mixing your $x$s and $y$s, I think...

Comment: Discriminant in x's is of degree $6$ and if we drop the degree then it is $S_4$ invariant.

Comment: "I know this is degree 6, not 4, but the point is that you shouldn't be mixing your $x$s and your $y$s"....

Comment: @Arturo Magidin, I have tried all possible ways to find one but nothings seemed work. Will it be possible to find one for me ? Thank you.

Comment: What about (x1-x2)(x3-x4)(y1-y3)(y2-y4) ?